# Create sptimer job in c# and/or powershell

Tags: powershell, timer-jobs, development

Can anyone tell me how to go about creating a timer job for sharepoint 2010 either using C# or Powershell.

All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://maraboustork.co.uk/index.php/2010/10/using-powershell-to-set-up-an-sptimerjob/) explains in great detail how to use powershell to create an sptimer job for sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 6):

Creating a Timer Job in Windows SharePoint Service 3.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686(office.12).aspx

Same principles for SharePoint 2010 I'm assuming, unless anyone else can differ?